# Redirecting static IP traffic to dynamic host

Tags: networking, router, static-ip

I want to host a service on my home network. My ISP unfortunately charges $30/Mo for static IP. However on my VPS host I can add that for just a $1/month. While my ISP gives me dynamic IP, I do have a ddns server so that I can access my home network using something like homenetwork.example.com Would it be possible to use my VPS static IP to opaquely route the traffic to my homenet.examople.com:xxxx port without the actual traffic going through the VPS (due to bandwidth limits) and without revealing the actual address of the destination?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No.

There are a number of partial solutions and answers, but the last sentence - masking your home IP and not routing traffic via VPS without additional resources - is not doable.

Have you considered getting a VPN with a static IP (its a thing, and not uncommon, but a different use case to what most people think of). The cost of this is comparatively low (US$5-US$20 per month)  and it ticks your boxes - masks your home IP, does not go through VPS.

Comment: eg https://www.purevpn.com/order-now.php can be had for less then $8 per month on a term contract - and you may very well be able to find further discounts.